# Is there a way to make org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet work with Jetty 11

Tags: jakarta-ee, cxf, embedded-jetty

I have a project by which I use an embedded Jetty server. We have now moved to **Jetty 11** which uses **jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet**. Previously we used Jetty 9 which was still using **javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet**. I know that we could go to **Jetty 10**, but is it possible to use **Jetty 11** with **CXFServlet** and if not does anyone know when this might be possible

Answer (score 1):

CXF needs to support to Jakarta EE 9 and Jakarta Servlet 5 before it will work.

Follow the issue tracking this effort at CXF.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8371